# How do you assert a run loop was used in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js, mocking, stubbing

I have this code inside an Ember service:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  semaphore.take(() => {
    this.get('limiter').removeTokens(1, () => {
      semaphore.leave();

      this.get('requestSender').sendRequest(url).then(data => {
        run(null, resolve, cache.put(url, data, cacheTime));
      }).catch(function() {
        run(null, reject, arguments);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I'm going through the limiter callback, so I need a run loop (to my understanding). I would like to assert in a unit test that a run loop was used. I can assert the promise resolves the correct value from the cache, but I don't know how to verify a run loop was used. In other words, I could remove the `run` call and all my tests would still pass, which is not desirable.

Things I've thought of that I don't want to resort to:

- I could use `Ember.run` instead of `run` and use stubbing and restoring, but I like to deconstruct globals at the top of the file (`const { run } = Ember;`), so I would not like to sacrifice that just for a test.
- I could wrap the run loop call in another Ember service so I can stub it, but that seems like overkill.

Basically I'm wondering if there are any events that fire when a run loop is entered that I can listen to in a test. It's OK if involves Ember privates.

Answer (score 0):

You could add argument to your method which would make your method of service more "testable". Analyse this fragment of code:

```
const Ember = {
  run() {
    console.log('ORIGINAL METHOD');
  }
};
const { run } = Ember;

const service = {
  method(runMethod) {
    let runToCall = runMethod ? runMethod : run;
    runToCall();
  }
};

// in application
service.method();

// in tests
function mockedRun() {
  console.log('REPLACED METHOD');  
};

service.method(mockedRun);
```

Which outputs:

> ORIGINAL METHOD
>
> REPLACED METHOD

Here's [demo](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20Ember%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20run()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%27ORIGINAL%20METHOD%27)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0Aconst%20%7B%20run%20%7D%20%3D%20Ember%3B%0A%0Aconst%20service%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20method(runMethod)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20runToCall%20%3D%20runMethod%20%3F%20runMethod%20%3A%20run%3B%0A%20%20%20%20runToCall()%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aservice.method()%3B%20%2F%2F%20in%20application%0A%0A%2F%2F%20in%20tests%0Afunction%20mockedRun()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%27REPLACED%20METHOD%27)%3B%20%20%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aservice.method(mockedRun)%3B).

Eventually you could use:

> I could wrap the run loop call in another Ember service so I can stub
> it, but that seems like overkill.

But seems like passing function as argument is simpler.

Comment: I agree simpler, but if I was to go this route, I would use a service as it is cleaner/better practice.

Answer (score 0):

Test will fail if run loop is not started because you'll get an assertion. Is this not enough?

Why do you need to assert that run loop was used?

Comment: I changed `run(null, resolve, cache.put(url, data, cacheTime))` to `resolve(cache.put(url, data, cacheTime))` and my tests still pass, no assertion errors. These are unit tests though, are you referring to acceptance tests?